# can <s:action> tag submit action as POST?

Tags: struts2, action

I have restriction in our application that if action declared as GET then only those action can be submit as GET method.
I want to know that can we submit **s:action** as POST method??
If Yes then please give me the guidance.
If not then what is the proper way to get call action from JSP and need the result in that JSP and the action should be post.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you were doing this without Struts at all, your question would be: Can I submit an HTML form with an HTTP POST method. Obviously, the answer is yes, simply add the method="POST" attribute to your form tag.

In Struts, you get the same behavior from the struts form tag (described here: https://struts.apache.org/docs/form.html).  In that doc, it shows that there is no default for the method attribute, but I would expect that to actually be the same as the default for the HTML form method - GET.  If you provide a struts form tag with a method="POST" you should be set.